# Error Using mex matlab 2014a windows x64

Tags: c++, matlab, windows-7-x64, mex

I got several errors while trying to use mex function on matlab 2014a with windows 7 x64. The most simple example of any mex generates the error listed as follows. I used windows 7.1 sdk compiler, vc++ 2010 compiler and vc++ compiler and the error doesn't change a thing. Anyone have experienced this issue as well while using this configurations? I would apreciatte some help with this.

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(37) : error C2143:   syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(37) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(37) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(42) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'f'
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(42) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(42) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(75) : error C2065: 'mxFunctionPtr' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(75) : error C2146:  syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'f'
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(75) : error C2513: 'const char **' : no variable declared before '='
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(75) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(120) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'mxArray'
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(171) : error C2065: 'mxArray' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(172) : error C2065: 'pa' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(172) : error C2182: 'mexMakeArrayPersistent' : illegal use of type 'void'
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\extern\include\mex.h(172) : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s);
```

stopping compilation

EDIT 1 :

as Sugested below, all the errors changed to this:

```
error C2014: preprocessor command must start as first
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'mxArray'
error C2065: 'nrhs' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'mexErrMsgIdAndTxt': identifier not found
error C3861: 'mexErrMsgIdAndTxt': identifier not found
error C2065: 'prhs' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'prhs' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'mxGetN': identifier not found
error C3861: 'mxGetN': identifier not found
error C3861: 'mexErrMsgIdAndTxt': identifier not found
error C2065: 'prhs' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'mxGetN': identifier not found
error C2065: 'prhs' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'mxGetPr': identifier not found
error C2065: 'prhs' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'mxGetPr': identifier not found
error C2065: 'prhs' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'mxGetM': identifier not found
error C2065: 'prhs' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'mxGetM': identifier not found
error C2065: 'plhs' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'mxREAL' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'mxCreateDoubleMatrix': identifier not

error C2065: 'plhs' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'mxGetPr': identifier not found
fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left
brace '{' at 'pukkernelMex.cpp(3)'    was matched
```

EDIT 2 - Contents of pukkernel:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
extern "C" { #include "mex.h" }

void pukKernel(double *A, double *B, int rowsA, int rowsB, int columns, double *out)
{    
    double w = 1.0;
    double s = 1.0;

    double cte1 = 1/s;
    double cte2 = sqrt(pow(2,(1/w))-1);

    for (int pattA = 0; pattA < rowsA; pattA++) {
        for (int pattB = 0; pattB < rowsB; pattB++) {
            double norma = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                norma += pow(A[pattA+(c)*rowsA] - B[pattB+(c)*rowsB], 2);
            }
            norma = sqrt(norma);
            double de = 2*norma;
            double aux = cte1 * de * cte2;

            out[pattA+(pattB)*rowsA] = 1 / pow((1+pow(aux,2)), w);
        }
    }

}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    if (nrhs != 2) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("Test:pukkernel:nrhs.",
                            "Two inputs required.");
    }

    if (nlhs != 1) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("Test:pukkernel:nlhs",
                      "One output required.");
    }

    if (mxGetN(prhs[0]) != mxGetN(prhs[1])) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("Test:pukkernel:differentDimensions",
                      "Input matrixes must have same dimensions.");
    }

    // Input
    int columns = mxGetN(prhs[0]);
    double *A = (double *) mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    double *B = (double *) mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    int rowsA = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    int rowsB = mxGetM(prhs[1]);

    // Output
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(rowsA, rowsB, mxREAL);
    double *outMatrix = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    pukKernel(A, B, rowsA, rowsB, columns, outMatrix);
}
```

Comment: Are you enclosing the header like this: `extern "C" { #include "mex.h" }` ?

Comment: this way?

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mex.h"

Comment: Your reply seems to indicate that you misunderstood my question. Is there an `extern C` around the mex.h include?

Comment: It was not the way you mentioned. So I switched to extern "C" {#include "mex.h"}, and the error changed to "modifier not found."
     pukkernelMex.cpp (31): error C2065: 'nrhs': undeclared identifier

Comment: Can you add the content of 'pukkernelMex.cpp' to the question?

Comment: Sure, i'm adding now.

Comment: The C2014 error is likely caused by formatting. Change the `extern "C" { #include "mex.h" } so that the `extern "C" {` is the first line, `#include "mex.h"` is the 2nd, and `}` is the 3rd.

Comment: Does `mex.h` include `matrix.h` by any chance? It seems like your IDE may not be including the needed MATLAB headers, since it can't find `mxarray`. That type should be defined in `matrix.h`, which I should think is included from `mex.h`, but double-check.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius The code was correct as it is (revert back to your original #include statements). I just tried it and it compiles fine: `mex -largeArrayDims pukkernelMex.cpp`. Just make sure to rename the file as C++ (i.e .cpp extension). Note that if you're using the Windows SDK, you'll need to make sure that x64 components were selected during installation.. Otherwise just install the full Visual Studio and it should take care of it for you. Remember to run `mex -setup` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! There was a issue at my instalation of Windows SDK. I Also changed the matlab version for a older version and it worked fine. Thanks a lot for the help!